# Java: Optimally handling many-to-many relation with huge data sets

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many

here is my issue. 
i have a huge amount of data in many-to-many tables that i have to update quite often and also request them with dynamic filters, order and request by location (postgis-db)...

shop entity:

```
public class Shop extends BaseEntity {

  ....

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JsonSerialize(using = IdSerializer.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Shop parent;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shops")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

  ...
}
```

product entity:

```
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JoinTable(name = "product_shop",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id"))
  private List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
```

the product table consists of about 1 million rows and the shops of about 8000. hence, the many-to-many table is 8*10^9 rows long in the worst case which results in really long request times.

any idea to solve this performantly with keeping in mind, that i want to sort the shops according to a location field which.

current tech stack:

- java 8
- spring boot
- hibernate / jpa
- postgresql / postgis

Comment: you should go with pagination!?

Comment: on top of this i use pagination of course